# How can I use text() with a multi-line string and plot the string from the y-coordinate down?

Tags: r, plot, text

How can I get the tops of both strings to be aligned on the plot?

```
library(stringr)
arep <- rep('a', 17) %>% 
  str_c(collapse = "\n")
brep <- rep('b', 10) %>% 
  str_c(collapse = "\n")

plot.new()

text(x = .5, y = .5, labels = arep)
text(x = .4, y = .5, labels = brep)
```

Answer (score 0):

At least this will work, although it is kind of a workaround:

```
arep <- rep('a', 17) %>% 
  str_c(collapse = "\n")
brep <- c(rep('b', 10), rep("", 7)) %>% 
  str_c(collapse = "\n")

plot.new()
text(x = .5, y = .5, labels = arep)
text(x = .4, y = .5, labels = brep)
```